# How to inspect JS files loaded with RequireJS using FF or Chrome?

Tags: requirejs

### The Goal

I am trying to dissect a client-side application that uses RequireJS to load its source.

### The Problem

As expected, the app loads up one main JS file that require()s and define()s other modules.  The main JS file is visible in Chrome's Dev Tools --> Resources.  All of the subsequently loaded modules are not.

How can I view JS files loaded as RequireJS modules in a way similar to how I would view JS files loaded by script tags?

Answer (score 1):

Take look at the `Sources` tab, there will you find all the loaded files. Maybe you have to click the small `show navigator` icon in the upper left corner of the source window.

Comment: Unfortunately this still only shows the initially loaded file that makes the require() calls.  I checked sources, content scripts, and snippets.  Thanks for taking the time to think about this.  Let me know if there is anything I can clarify.

Comment: Are you sure the files are loaded, cause that the way it works for me. Can you set a break point writting `debugger` somewhere in some of your modules, cause then it must open source tab.

Comment: JS files show up in Network and Resources if they are loaded correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid you will be able to see any JS files as it seems that the client-side application which you are trying to debug is an optimize version of RequireJS.

RequireJS optimizer is a tool which combines all the define() and require() scripts into single file this helps to reduce server side call or for that matter there is only one call to server side. Think of it just like minified version of most of the standard libraries

Comment: If I understand RequireJS correctly (I'm somewhat new to it), there is a distinction here between the RequireJS loader, which does not combine the scripts on its own, and the r.js optimizer, which does combine them. It might be helpful to know if the OP is actually running r.js and using the build versions of the scripts, or is simply using RequireJS as a dynamic loader.

Comment: Yep, that's true. Minified version is created only after running r.js

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue when i loaded a .js file with

```
$("#element").load("thisIsMyJsFile.js");
```

and I wanted to debug "thisIsMyJsFile.js" in "sources" in chrome.
**add this line in the "thisIsMyJsFile.js" file:**

```
//# sourceURL=browsertools://thisIsMyJsFile.js
```

**change "thisIsMyJsFile.js" with your file name.**
and
it will be shown in the source when you inspect element.